# Book Recommendation for Second Course in Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, soft-question

I only took a non-rigorous linear algebra course (It was designed for non-math students). I finished most of Hungerford's algebra. Now I have two choices to study more advanced linear algebra: Hoffman's linear algebra, Finite dimensional vector spaces by Halmos. I already looked at the first chapter of both books. I think Halmos goes at a faster pace which is something I like. Would I miss anything if I start learning the book of Halmos instead of Hoffman's ?

Thank you

Comment: Why do you only have two choices?

Comment: @DanielMcLaury These are the books that are in my university's library

Comment: Does this answer your question? [High-level linear algebra book](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/433858/high-level-linear-algebra-book)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the evidence of your "mathematical maturity" from Questions asked and Answered, if you find the pace of Halmos to your liking, then I'd continue with that.

Hoffman/Kunze is often an advanced undergraduate or beginning graduate linear algebra text.  If you have time you might want to sample its exercises after finishing the Halmos book.