# learning linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, self-learning, learning

So I'm a college student that has taken 3 semesters of calc/diff eq/linear algebra and I think linear algebra has been by far my favorite course so far and I would love to know more in the subject, the style of a consistent theorem/proof approach really appealed to me. So I ask what is a good book or resource to learn more advanced linear algebra or should is there other subjects I need to come to grips with first?

specifically I'd like to become more familiar with metrics/tensors

Comment: See also [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/433858/high-level-linear-algebra-book).

Comment: Since you're interested in tensors, you might also like to learn about integration on manifolds.

Answer (score 3):

Given your level, I would say that an excellent book would be "Linear Algebra Done Right" by Axler. His book is less computational than most and a great second proof-based course in LA.
[http://www.amazon.com/Linear-Algebra-Right-Undergraduate-Mathematics/dp/3319110799/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1461267526&sr=1-1&keywords=linear+algebra+done+right](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3319110799)

But, perhaps you want something even more challenging, in which case, I'd recommend "Linear Algebra" by Hoffman and Kunze.
[http://www.amazon.com/Linear-Algebra-Edition-Kenneth-Hoffman/dp/0135367972](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0135367972)

Answer (score 1):

Without a doubt, ["Linear Algebra"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387964126) by Serge Lang.

(A note of caution-there is also "'Introduction to Linear Algebra" by Lang-a fine book by itself, but from your question, you are looking for a more advanced text, like the first.)