# Book to learn Advanced Linear Algebra and Matrix Theory

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, reference-request, soft-question, book-recommendation

I am looking for a book to learn Advanced Linear Algebra and Matrix Theory in detail.

**Sheldon Axler :Doesn't cover matrix theory,Hoffman,Kunze:Doesn't have many exercises and examples on each of the topics**

Please suggest some alternatives

**Requisites:** Theorems with proofs,easy ones left to reader,Enough examples,Good Exercises(with Hints if possible)

**Topics to cover**:

> 1. Systems of Linear equations
>
>    2. Diagonalization of a square matrix
>    3. Vector Spaces
>    4. Solutions of Linear Systems: Gaussian elimination
>         , Null Space and Range
>         , Rank and nullity, Consistency conditions in terms of rank
>         , General Solution of a linear system
>         , Elementary Row and Column operations
>         , Row  Reduced Form
>         ,Triangular Matrix Factorization
>
> 5.Important Subspaces associsted with a matrix: Range and Null space, Rank and Nullity,Rank Nullity theorem .
>
> 6.Orthogonality: Inner product, Inner product Spaces
>   , Cauchy – Schwarz inequality
>   , Norm
>   , Orthogonality
>   , Gram – Schmidt orthonormalization
>   , Orthonormal basis
>   , Expansion in terms of orthonormal basis – Fourier
>   series
>   , Orthogonal complement.
>
> 7.Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors
>
> 8. Hermitian Matrices:Real symmetric and Hermitian Matrices
>      Properties of eigenvalues and eigenvectors.
>
> 9.General Matrices: The matrices $AA^T,A^TA$
>    Rank, Nullity, Range and Null Space of $AA^T,A^TA$
>   ,Singular Value Decomposition.
>
> 10.Jordan Cnonical form:
>    Primary Decomposition Theorem
>    Nilpotent matrices
>    Canonical form for a nilpotent matrix

*Mostly results on MSE said to follow Matrix Analysis-Horn,Johnson but the book does not cover all the topics in great detail.It focuses on more advanced topics.*

Please suggest  a book accordingly as I need to prepare for my exam.

Comment: Strang's texts also an option here (at least in terms of topics covered).  Not the greatest for proof questions, but he has some interesting conceptual questions, I guess.

Comment: Linear Algebra Done Right - Sheldon Axler

Comment: Another possibility: take a look at [Matrix Analysis and Applied Linear Algebra](https://www.amazon.com/Matrix-analysis-applied-linear-algebra/dp/0898714540/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1507272019&sr=8-3&keywords=matrix+analysis) by Carl Meyer. I believe it covers all of the topics you listed, is quite detailed, and has lots of exercises. And (at least at the time I bought it), it comes bundled with a solution manual, as well as a CD-ROM containing a PDF copy of the book.

Comment: @MorganRodgers I agree there may some things that are on his list but missing in the book but as far as I could tell a great majority of the listed items are in that book. And I think LADR is one of the most lucidly written linear algebra texts.

Comment: Check [this](https://www.amazon.com/Problems-Theorems-Translations-Mathematical-Monographs/dp/0821802364/ref=sr_1_2?dchild=1&keywords=prasolov+linear+algebra&qid=1631486138&s=books&sr=1-2)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [High-level linear algebra book](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/433858/high-level-linear-algebra-book)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I loved Linear Algebra by Friedberg Insel and Spence

The book by Lax is also excellent.

Answer (score 7):

I highly recommend *[A Second Course in Linear Algebra](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1107103819)*, by Garcia and Horn.

Reviews by:

- the [MAA](https://www.maa.org/press/maa-reviews/a-second-course-in-linear-algebra-0); and
- [Nicholas Higham](https://nickhigham.wordpress.com/2017/06/08/a-second-course-in-linear-algebra-by-garcia-and-horn-2017/).

**EDIT:** The second-edition is now titled *[Matrix Mathematics: A Second Course in Linear Algebra](https://www.cambridge.org/highereducation/books/matrix-mathematics/3BBCFAFD942BAF6A0813763297D69E65)*.

Answer (score 0):

[The Linear Algebra a Beginning Graduate Student Ought to Know](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/940072635X) has a pretty good presentation of all this material. It's got some less standard notations and terminology, but it's a good, detailed look at advanced linear algebra and matrix theory.