# Exercise books in linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, book-recommendation

I'm going to find some Exercise books in linear algebra  and I was wondering if there are some exercise books (that is, books with ***solved*** problems and exercises) 
The books I'm searching for should be:

- full of *hard*, *non-obvious*, *non-common*, and *thought-provoking* problems;
- rich of *complete*, *step by step*, *rigorous*, and *enlightening* solutions;

Thanks in advance

Comment: I will refer you to this link
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/433858/high-level-linear-algebra-book

Comment: Schaum's Outline of Linear Algebra

Answer (score 0):

The book you are looking for is [Problems and Theorems in Linear Algebra (Translations of Mathematical Monographs, Vol. 134) Paperback – June 13, 1994
by V. V. Prasolov](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821802364). There is much fuller second edition, but as far as I know it was not translated (yet) into English.

Answer (score 0):

Try Paul Halmos' *Linear Algebra Problem Book*.

Answer (score 0):

The Berkeley problems also have a number of good linear algebra exercises. https://link.springer.com/book/9780387204291