# Linear algebra study material recommendation

Tags: linear-algebra, book-recommendation

I have done an introductory course in Linear Algebra, but It wasn’t a proof-based course. I think I can deal with the applied part of linear algebra, but I don’t understand things like spaces and Linear mapping very well. I spent sometime reading the book: Linear algebra done right, but the language was ambigious  and I spent alot of time reading a single paper in the book, so I fhink I lack  some of the basis. Based on what I said, I would be glad if you recommend to me how I should start.

Comment: Read 'Finite Dimensional Vector Spaces' from P. R. Halmos. It avoids the concrete approach like the plague and some exercises assumes you know things like Zorn's Lemma and linear ODEs. But all in all it's an excellent second book on Linear Algebra.

Comment: Probably, you can find a good recommendation [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2377980/70305) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4335/70305) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2921922/70305) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2864113/70305) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2718787/70305) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2764111/70305) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2574132/70305) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2402775/70305)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prerequisites/Books for A First Course in Linear Algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/43930/prerequisites-books-for-a-first-course-in-linear-algebra)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend starting with Friedberg's Linear Algebra book or Lang's one. They're both great theoretical books.

Answer (score 0):

Axler's *Linear Algebra Done Right* is nice.