# I'm looking for similar books to the second course of linear algebra by Brown

Tags: reference-request

I want another reference for a second course in linear algebra. I have no problems with Brown's book, even more I found it very usefull and well written. I just want another reference book for self-study between middle and high level.
Thank you.

Comment: See the "third level books" in my answer to [High-level linear algebra book](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/433858/high-level-linear-algebra-book).