# Textbook recommendation for Advanced (undergrad) Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, soft-question, book-recommendation

I am a pure math major.  I am taking a one-semester course covering the following topics:

Inner Product Spaces, 
Direct Sums of Subspaces,
  Primary Decomposition Theorem,
Reduction - (triangular, Jordan, rational, classical),
Dual Spaces,
Orthogonal Direct Sums,
Quadratic Forms

Our lecturer is a number theorist so he will probably make some links with number theory.  He does not recommend any textbooks for the course but I learn best alone out of books designed for self-study.  Lecture theaters full of whispering and distractions are hell to me!
I like books that are written in a personal, quirky style that prompt deep reflection and encourage independent thinking.  I like colorful motivating material!!  I dislike mention of any "real-world applications" (ie physics/engineering).  I hate when writers leave out big chunks in proofs and say the missing steps are "trivial" when they are not.  I like it when solutions are available to the exercises.

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Seems like [Halmos's](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387900933) book fits your description except that his book is not colorful and that a solution manual does not exist (if you find it let me know!).

Comment: Possibly relevant: [High-level linear algebra book](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/433858/13130)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [High-level linear algebra book](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/433858/high-level-linear-algebra-book)

Answer (score 1):

I like [Axler's Linear Algebra done Right](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783319110790) as a simple, but powerful introduction into  theoretical aspects of linear algebra, and [Kostrikin-Manin's book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/2881246834)  as a very efficient 
reference for a second read.

Answer (score 1):

While studying this course, I used to refer to [this book by Pramod Kumar](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=OaW6R0I-5usC&pg=PA254&dq=primary+decomposition+theorem+linear+algebra&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjdoNLriMnkAhWpIbcAHf23CfcQuwUIZTAI#v=onepage&q=primary%20decomposition%20theorem%20linear%20algebra&f=false) which proved to be very useful and which I think has a lot of topics that are in your syllabus covered.

Also, I would recommend you giving [Steven Roman’s book](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387728285) a try.