# Reference request - textbook on linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, soft-question

I'm looking for a textbook on linear algebra that is on a level higher than that of a first-read text, but isn't of the machine-gun-definition-theorem-proof-corollary type. I used Lay's text as an introduction to the subject, and then picked up Hoffman and Kunze. The topics themselves are understandable, but the text is quite dry, as I feel like most of what's going on lacks motivation - things seem to come out of nowhere. So I'd like something that's more focused and advanced than an introductory text, but doesn't feel like reading a dictionary of the terms used in linear algebra. Thanks.

Comment: I liked Friedberg, Insel, Spence

Comment: Does this answer your question? [High-level linear algebra book](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/433858/high-level-linear-algebra-book)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am also partial to Friedberg, Insel, and Spence. Loehr is a more advanced text and very comprehensive, but also quite good.

It might be worthwhile to work through the material with an application in mind. I found combinatorics to be a very helpful vantage point when I took Linear Algebra. The Babai--Frankl text Linear Algebra Methods in Combinatorics is a very nice text, that might be helpful in cementing concepts like linear independence, eigenvalues, etc.