# Advanced Book on Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, jordan-normal-form, schur-decomposition

After I took a Linear Algebra class I often found many Linear Algebra results that weren't covered in the class. I would like to learn these results therefore I am looking for a book, or even Notes written in Latex, that need to satisfy the following characteristics :

1. Covering topics on linear algebra that are generally not covered in basic linear algebra courses, in particular matrix decomposition formulas like the polar decomposition, the Schur decomposition and the Jordan Canonical form.
   I would also like to learn about the Gershgorin cirle theorems, matrix norms and their inequalities (for example the Hadamard inequality), and any "interesting" theorem about matrices, for example the fact that complex diagonalizable matrices are dense.
2. The book need to not focus on numerical methods, I want to learn these topics in order to use them when i need to, maybe for proving a statement, definitely not to solve a linear system by numerical methods.
3. It's preferable that the book doesn't spend too much time talking about "basic stuff" like the definition of a vector space, of a matrix etc. This is because I already took a course in Linear Algebra so I already know these topics
4. I would like the book to have advanced exercises, definitely not basic exercises like "compute this vector in this base". I would like the exercises to allow you to deepen the theory, basically like the exercises in Baby Rudin book

Comment: I wouldn't understate the importance of basic exercises

Comment: I don't find them very useful when I already took a linear algebra course

Comment: See [High-level linear algebra book](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/433858/13130).

Comment: Check out Matrix Analysis by Horn and Johnson.

Comment: Since you mentioned numerical methods, I highly recommend Matrix Analysis and Applied Linear Algebra by Meyer. Yes, it does include a lot of introductory topics, but you can skip those. And, as mentioned, Matrix Analysis by Horn and Johnson.

Comment: I mentioned numerical methods to clarify that my goal isn't to focus on them

Comment: Ah, sorry misread. Nevertheless, it's a nice book, and certainly not as dense as the one by Horn and Johnson.

Comment: are you interested in working over arbitrary fields or just $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb C$?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [High-level linear algebra book](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/433858/high-level-linear-algebra-book)

Answer (score 2):

[*Matrix Mathematics A Second Course in Linear Algebra*](https://www.cambridge.org/highereducation/books/matrix-mathematics/3BBCFAFD942BAF6A0813763297D69E65#overview) shall be published in July 2023, written by Stephan Ramon Garcia (Pomona College) + Roger A. Horn (University of Utah).

Mark Hunacek reviewed the [first edition on 3/22/2018 for the MAA](https://www.maa.org/press/maa-reviews/a-second-course-in-linear-algebra-0).

Answer (score 1):

The book here is good: https://mtaylor.web.unc.edu/notes/linear-algebra-notes/

It covers many of the topics you are looking for. The book does have some "advanced exercises" to develop some interesting results.