# Seeking Advice: Optimal Study Methods and Sources for Advanced Linear Algebra Topics

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, computer-science, book-recommendation

Hello Math Stack Exchange community,

I'm currently looking to delve deeper into advanced topics in linear algebra, including system of linear equations, eigenvalues and eigenvectors, vector spaces, linear mappings and their applications, and iterative methods. I am seeking advice on the most optimal study methods and sources for mastering these subjects.

Could you please recommend:

Comprehensive textbooks that cover these topics thoroughly and provide clear explanations and examples?
Online courses or tutorials that offer in-depth coverage of these advanced linear algebra concepts?
Effective practice problems and resources to reinforce understanding and problem-solving skills?
Any supplementary resources such as software tools or additional lectures that may aid in my study?
I appreciate any recommendations or insights you can provide. Thank you for your help!

Best regards,
Hassan

Comment: I wouldn’t say those are advanced topics, rather the fundamentals. And the optimal learning path for me is likely different for you. _Linear Algebra Done Right_ by Axler might suit you.

Comment: Strang's [linear algebra course on MIT OpenCourseware](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/18-06-linear-algebra-spring-2010/) is very popular and includes video lectures, assignments, and exams to supplement the textbook.

Comment: [**Linear Algebra and Its Applications**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0030105676) by Gilbert Strang is a fairly standard upper undergraduate level (for U.S. colleges and universities) applied linear algebra text. Strang's book belongs to the 2nd level books in the categorization I discuss in [this MSE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/433944/13130). I see that @littleO has also mentioned Strang while I was writing this comment.

Comment: I personally like to have a look at lecture notes of universities (e.g. https://people.math.ethz.ch/~kowalski/script-la.pdf).